# Error while trying to install Nvidia drivers

Tags: software-installation, make, paths

Getting this error:
Unable to find the development tool `make` in your
path; please make sure that you have the package
'make' installed.  If make is installed on your
system, then please check that `make` is in your
PATH.

Comment: Usually it is not a good idea to compile your GPU drivers - instead use the "Additional drivers" tab in "Settings". Or use karel's suggestion. Background: The drivers are compiled against your kernel headers - if they change you have to recompile

Answer (score 3):

GNU Make is a utility which controls the generation of executables and other target files of a program from the program's source files. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install make
```

Ubuntu has a built-in ubuntu-drivers program that can decide automatically which proprietary graphics drivers to install, and streamlines the installation of Nvidia drivers. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install   
sudo reboot
```

The `install` option of `ubuntu-drivers` installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies.